# How to enforce parameterization of generics

Tags: java, generics, collections

I'm wondering if there's a way to ensure that a generically typed class is always parameterized. Illustration below:

```
class CustomList<T extends SpecialItem> {
}

class MyItem extends SpecialItem {
}
```

The intended usage is as follows:

```
    class MyClass {
       private CustomList<MyItem> itemsList;
    }
```

Is there a way to prohibit the following usage syntactically?

```
    class MyClass {
       private CustomList itemsList;
    }
```

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: Well, you can configure your IDE (at least in Eclipse it's possible) to issue errors instead of warnings whenever raw types are used, but that would apply to any raw types, not just your specific class.

Comment: Does this mean that the Java compiler does not give a possibility to achieve this?

Comment: It means that the Java language doesn't forbid usage of raw types.

Comment: What's the reason you need this?

Comment: The Java compiler already flags the use of raw types with a warning.  If someone chooses to ignore that warning, they are willfully writing code with mistakes in it.  There is no mechanical way to stop this;  it requires a human solution, in the form of coding standards (like “must build with zero warnings using -Xlint”) and/or code reviews.

Comment: It's a debatable topic whether the warnings are just enough or not, as the needs could be quite diverse. But important thing is to understand the current behavior, which is clear from the answers. Thanks!

Comment: The reason, by the way, is backwards compatibility. It's one of the most important contributors to Java's success, and also one of its greatest disadvantages. In order to be able to compile 1.4 and earlier code in Java 1.5 and later, you're allowed to use raw types. Nowadays, this doesn't seem to make much sense, but it definitely did when Java 1.5 was all new and shiny.